# Anuglar, focus on inputs dynamically shown

Tags: angular, input

I have a component that shows/hides an input in elements added via a loop:

```
<div *ngFor="item of items">
  <div class="container">
    <div *ngIf="selectedItem !== item.id">
      <p>{{item.name}}</p><span (click)="showInput(item.id)">edit</span>
    </div>

    <div *ngIf="selectedItem === item.id">
      <p><input type="text" [value]="item.name" /></p><span (click)="hideInput()">edit</span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

selectedItem: string;
...
showInput(id: string) {
  this.selectedItem = id;
}

hideInput() {
  this.selectedItem = null;
}
```

I tried using `@ViewChild` on the input but if inside the `ngIf` it returned `undefined`. Setting `autofocus` on the input works the first time but once show/hide more than once it stops working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-j3ufam) that focuses the input element after clicking edit.

The `autofocus` attribute only works once because its intended to be used at page load. Check out this [link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/select#attr-autofocus) for more information.